# How to access an object array as Hashvalue in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, hash

Why does the following throws the compile error `[] cannot be applied to object.` (rough translation from german)?

```
Hashtable entrys = new Hashtable();
string keyPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Test";
string entryName = "testName";

entrys.Add(entryName, new object[]{256, RegistryValueKind.DWord}); // seems to work

foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in entrys)
{
    Registry.SetValue(keyPath,
                      (string)entry.Key,
                      entry.Value[0],   // error here
                      entry.Value[1]);  // and here
}
```

I expected `entry.Value` to be an array of objects but apparently the compiler thinks it's just an object. What is wrong here?

Comment: check this for correct usage of Registry.SetValue -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string, object[]>` instead of `Hashtable`. Hashtable isn't strongly typed

Comment: You need to cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming because `DictionaryEntry` does not have an array as a property for Value. Below is the structure of `DictionaryEntry`. You must use `entry.Value` instead of `entry.Value[0]`

```
    // Summary:
    // Defines a dictionary key/value pair that can be set or retrieved.
    [Serializable]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public struct DictionaryEntry
    {            
        public DictionaryEntry(object key, object value);

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the key in the key/value pair.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The key in the key/value pair.
        public object Key { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the value in the key/value pair.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The value in the key/value pair.
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

To make it work you have to cast it. Use following code

```
Registry.SetValue(keyPath,
                  (string)entry.Key,
                  ((object[])(entry.Value))[0]);
```

Comment: So that means `entrys.Add(entryName, new object[]{256, RegistryValueKind.DWord});` is actually not valid because a DictionaryEntry cannot hold an array as value? 
I thought `entry.Value` returns my object-array which I could acces via `[]`-operator?
Should I use an `ArrayList` instead or what could I do?

Comment: I have edited my answer. See the EDIT portion. Its working.

Comment: entry.Value is an object array, the dictionary is just not aware of that. That's why casting works. You might wanna use a   `System.Collection.Generic.HashSet<object[]>` since it has a generic implementation (allows you to choose a type for the items).